# XSLT concat with <value-of> and text Href

Tags: html, xslt, href

I'm trying to concatenate some text and values into a Href.

Basically i need to concatenate this :

String with part of the link: `http://server/area/graphic.aspx?ns=`

After the `ns=` i need to use `<xsl:value-of select="number">`

Then add `&nocache=5555`

and concat all this values to create this

'http://server/area/graphic.aspx?ns=9999&nocache=5555'

Then put this in a Href to use it as an image.

i've tried some stuff but nothing seems to work ..

Thanks

EDIT: ok most of the stuff i tried just comepletly failed, but i got this , this is the closest i got to getting it right

```
<xsl:template match="MODULO[NAME='Identity']" name="Tmp_Identificacao">
    <img>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        http://server/area/graphic.aspx?ns=<xsl:value-of 
        select="substring-before(VALUES/ROW/number,'-')"/>&#160;nocache=5555
    </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
</template>

 <MODULO>
    <NAME>ObtemIdentificacao_P</NAME>
    <VALUES>
      <ROW>
        <number>9999</number>
     </ROW>
   <VALUES>
<MODULO>
```

The code runs , and it show's everything it needs , besides the image , I've tried inspecting the element and came up whit something , the `src` of the image doesn't show the value of the VALUES/ROW/number and it doesn't show the & before `nocache`
like this

```
<img src="http://server/area/graphic.aspx?ns= nocache=5555">
```

only thing i need to get this working is to put the value of the number and the `&` before `nocache`
Other than this i don't know what i can show , thanks in advance

PS:this is part of a big XSLT file , there's is nothing wrong with code beside this image im trying to implement.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates) here, but to give a precise answer, can you edit your question to show a sample of your XML and the XSLT you have currently tried? Thanks!

Comment: I've edited it, hope you can help! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind to have the `&` escaped as `&amp;` in the URL you can use this XML:

```
<img href="{concat('http://server/area/graphic.aspx?ns=', number, '&amp;nocache=5555')}" />
```

**Output:** (current node = `ROW`)

```
<img href="http://server/area/graphic.aspx?ns=9999&amp;nocache=5555"/>
```

Comment: The only thing that doesn't seem to work is the number,  i've tried to use '&'  before it but it doesn't seem to work aswell , everything else is perfect..

Comment: Probably you are at a different current node. Try `VALUES/ROW/number` instead of `number`. BTW the problem with your usage of `substring-before(...)` is: if the string does not contain the char `-` the returned string will be empty. So you'd have to check that beforehand.

Comment: Thanks i've got it to work, it was a problem with the substring-before(...), but my concat was also wrongly done , you've made me see both my problems :p thanks!

Comment: Even better is `<img href="http://server/area/graphic.aspx?ns={number}&amp;nocache=5555" />`